# How to convert a txt file with dictionary format to dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, dictionary

I have a file comprising data like,

```
{"cid": "ABCD", "text": "alphabets", "time": "1 week", "author": "xyz"}
{"cid": "EFGH", "text": "verb", "time": "2 week", "author": "aaa"}
{"cid": "IJKL", "text": "noun", "time": "3 days", "author": "nop"}
```

I wish to read this file and create a dataframe like,

```
cid     text    time    author
ABCD    alpha   1week   xyz
EFGH    verb    2week   aaa
IJKL    noun    3days   nop
```

Comment: is this a text/csv? also how are you getting this data into the file?

Comment: Have you looked into <dict>.keys and <dict>.values

Comment: it's a text file generated from an application.

Comment: If you are handling a txt file look into `json` python library for transforming text to dicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try reading the file as csv with a different seperator and grabbing the first column , then apply `ast.literal_eval` to convert to actual dictionary and convert back to dataframe:

```
import ast
output = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('file.txt',sep='|',header=None).iloc[:,0]
         .apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
```

---

```
print(output)

    cid       text    time author
0  ABCD  alphabets  1 week    xyz
1  EFGH       verb  2 week    aaa
2  IJKL       noun  3 days    nop
```

Working example:

```
file = """{"cid": "ABCD", "text": "alphabets", "time": "1 week", "author":"xyz"}
{"cid": "EFGH", "text": "verb", "time": "2 week", "author": "aaa"}
{"cid": "IJKL", "text": "noun", "time": "3 days", "author": "nop"}"""

import io #dont need for reading a file directly , just for example
import ast
print(pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file),sep='|',header=None).iloc[:,0]
             .apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()))
```

---

```
    cid       text    time author
0  ABCD  alphabets  1 week    xyz
1  EFGH       verb  2 week    aaa
2  IJKL       noun  3 days    nop
​
```